# Pandas Dataframe sum row based on column header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe and want to create two columns, one will show the amount MTD and the other will show the cumulative YTD based on a date parameter for each Account Name. This is easily achievable in Excel using a =SUMIFS formula and want to know the Python equivalent.

```
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Account Names | 31/01/2022 | 28/02/2022 | 31/03/2022 | 30/04/2022 |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Cash At Bank  |        100 |        150 |        100 |        150 |
| Debtors       |         50 |         50 |         50 |        100 |
| Inventory     |        250 |        250 |        350 |        100 |
| PAYG Withheld |         50 |         50 |         10 |        150 |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Ideally, I'd want this to be as efficient as possible i.e. doesn't require loops. I went the route of trying to do this using np.select as I've read this is one of the fastest methods, but had no luck. I get the following error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

```
EndDate = '31/03/2022'
Budget_Assets["MTD_Amount"] = np.select(condlist=[Budget_Assets.columns == EndDate],choicelist=[Budget_Assets[EndDate]],default=0)
```

For example, the value in the MTD_Amount column for Cash At Bank should be 100 and the YTD_Column will be 350 (sum of numbers from '31/01/2022' to '31/03/2022')

Comment: Please don't show your data as image, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No problem, I've made it much more succinct as well.

Comment: @Jered How do you calculate `MTD_Amount`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh MTD_Amount is just the value on the corresponding column for the month that I set as the parameter i.e. If the EndDate parameter is 31/03/2022, then the values will be the entire 31/03/2022 column and the YTD_Amount will be everything from 31/01/2022 to the 31/03/2022 column e.g. Cash at Bank will be 350, Debtors will be 150  for YTD. MTD = Month-to-Date. YTD = Year-to-Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `sum(axis=1)` by slicing the datetime like columns to calculate `YTD` and just use `loc` to get `MTD`

```py
EndDate = '31/03/2022'
date_cols = df.filter(regex='\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')
date_cols.columns = pd.to_datetime(date_cols.columns, dayfirst=True)

df['YTD_Column'] = date_cols.loc[:, :pd.to_datetime(EndDate, dayfirst=True)].sum(axis=1)
df['MTD_Column'] = df[EndDate]
```

```
   Account Names  31/01/2022  28/02/2022  31/03/2022  30/04/2022  YTD_Column  MTD_Column
0   Cash At Bank         100         150         100         150         350         100
1        Debtors          50          50          50         100         150          50
2      Inventory         250         250         350         100         850         350
3  PAYG Withheld          50          50          10         150         110          10
```

Comment: Does the YTD just sum the entire row? What happens if I want to to stop summing at '31/03/2022' and there are more columns with dates. I've updated my original to add another column.

Comment: Appreciate the fast response! Thank you